# How to Adjust the sorting dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jVwVJRmL-4M/T638dHzocNI/AAAAAAAAACU/8OLqf8cDDQc/w785-h247-k/sample.JPG]

I have a jqgrid,and I have a SortNo field which handling my sorting, how could I dynamically adjust its sorting when I add the same number in sortNo and automatically adjust the number by sequence. Please see in my sample in the link above. Can someone please help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var xaxis=645
var yaxis = $(document).height();
yaxis = yaxis-100;  
getGrids();

$("#maingrid").jqGrid({
    url:'models/gridheaders.php?todo=select&id=new',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['ID','Description_EN','Description_JP',
    'SortNo','ColWidth','GridID','Module'],
    colModel :[ 
        {name:'id', index:'id', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:false,editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                        

        {name:'eng', index:'eng', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                   

        {name:'jap', index:'jap', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}}, 
        //This field is I want to dynamically sort.
        {name:'sort', index:'sort', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                         

        {name:'col', index:'col', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,
        edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},                    

        {name:'grid', index:'grid', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,hidden:true,edittype:"text",
        editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"},editrules: { edithidden: true}}, 

        {name:'used', index:'used', width:120, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true,hidden:true,edittype:"text",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"},editrules: { edithidden: true}},  

        },
    ],
    viewrecords: true,          
    rowNum: -1,
    height: yaxis,
    width: xaxis,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    multiselect: true,
    editurl:""
});
```

Can someone help me, what function should I use to have a dynamic sorting? Thanks

Comment: Could you link to the actual jqgrid, show some code, write exactly what behavior you'd expect from that plugin and/or anything which would make this a real question? If you don't show any code or links, do you expect us to read your mind or hack into your computer to get the code and edit it so it can do the sorting? You know the question will be closed again if you don't add details..

Comment: [**DO. NOT. REPOST. THE. SAME. QUESTION. IMMEDIATELY. AFTER. THE. LAST. ONE. WAS. CLOSED.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561512/how-to-automatically-adjust-the-sorting)

Comment: sorry, but I need help, Can you help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can check DataTables. It can be easily integrated with jQuery and jQuery UI, and it includes multi column sorting.

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Comment: That is not my problem, my problem is if I add in the same number in sortNo field, and add the same number the number below or above will automatic adjust its number numerically. please see in my sample picture above..Thanks